# How do I allocate a key shortcut to moving GNOME 3 workspaces up/down?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, gnome3, gnome-shell, workspaces

In GNOME 3, in the Keyboard Shortcuts area of the Keyboard settings page, it is possible to allocate shortcuts to move between workspaces and move windows between workspaces.

Unfortunately, however, there is no ability to move workspaces *themselves* up/down. Is there a way I can achieve this through a custom shortcut? Is there, perhaps, a good extension out there?

I haven't been able to find out, so if anyone could answer my questions I would be immensely grateful. :)